# Feature testing rake tasks adds up the output to stdout. How to avoid this?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, stdout

I try to feature test a Rake Task and capture its output:

This is a full integration test (feature test), which
means I want to test it end-to-end. So I am not interested in stubbing
out some ConsoleRenderer class, just testing that when I run the task, I
see certain output in `stdout`.

The implementation, greatly simplified is

```
namespace :output do
  task :world do
    print 'hello world'
  end

  task :mars do
    print 'hello mars'
  end
end
```

And the feature test (rspec 3.3):

```
require 'feature_helper'

describe 'some output' do
  before do
    Rails.application.load_tasks
  end

  after do
    Rake::Task['output:world'].reenable
    Rake::Task['output:mars'].reenable
  end

  it 'outputs' do
    expect { Rake::Task['output:world'].invoke }.to output('hello world').to_stdout
  end

  it 'outputs again' do
    expect { Rake::Task['output:world'].invoke }.to output('hello world').to_stdout
  end

  it 'outputs mars' do
    expect { Rake::Task['output:mars'].invoke }.to output('hello mars').to_stdout
  end
end
```

When running this, somehow the output of the past runs is added up:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/features/output_spec.rb --order defined
.FF

Failures:

  1) some output outputs again
     Failure/Error: expect { Rake::Task['output:world'].invoke }.to output('hello world').to_stdout
       expected block to output "hello world" to stdout, but output "hello worldhello world"
     # ./spec/features/output_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) some output outputs mars
     Failure/Error: expect { Rake::Task['output:mars'].invoke }.to output('hello mars').to_stdout
       expected block to output "hello mars" to stdout, but output "hello marshello marshello mars"
     # ./spec/features/output_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

To illustrate, I run the test in order of definition.
The first test passes. The second fails, because somehow it includes the
output of the `$stdout` in the previous test, or runs itself twice. Same for the third (which seems to run itself thrice).

I suspect this is something in the Rake task, because when I simplify
the tests to merely `print` something, this adding does not occur:

```
it 'outputs' do
  expect { print 'hello world' }.to output('hello world').to_stdout
end

it 'outputs again' do
  expect { print 'hello world' }.to output('hello world').to_stdout
end

it 'outputs mars' do
  expect { print 'hello mars' }.to output('hello mars').to_stdout
end
```

This passes just fine.

Note that, on a console running

```
Rake::Task['output:mars'].invoke
Rake::Task['output:mars'].reenable
Rake::Task['output:mars'].invoke
```

Outputs "hello mars" once, then "hello mars" again. The issue does not
reproduce itself in such an environment.

What do I need to reset, reenable, re-import, truncate or otherwise
change, so that the output is not adding up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `reenable` was not the right thing to call. Instead, I should have used [`clear`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html#method-c-clear). Which by its own documentation is "Normally used in the unit tests.".

```
after do
  Rake.application.clear
end
```

**Note:** This fixes it, but I still don't know why exactly nor how the setup as described in the question runs the tasks three times at some point. So an answer that explains *why* the behaviour is like it is and *why* running `clear` does not have that, will be preferred over my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is executed twice or three times, is because you loaded the tasks before each block:

```
before do
  Rails.application.load_tasks
end
```

instead using `before :all`
And optionally use `Rails.application.clear` before loading, because if you loaded the tasks in another spec, they will still be there